# Nginx define retries for a certain route

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Is there a way to define retry for a certain URL route. In case of high load we might engage upstream timeouts, in our case Uwsgi. In most cases, we can ignore the timeouts and the rejected requests. But for a certain route I would like Nginx to retry x times.